# How can I get clipPath SVG on a pseudoelement to work in IE11/Edge besides a data url?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, border, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a rounded gradient border where the content can be transparent. This rules out the standard approaches of putting a background gradient element underneath the content. The other requirement is that it works down to IE11 and Edge 44/EdgeHTML 18.

This works great on Chrome/Firefox/Safari but Microsoft doesn't like a CSS clip-path referencing an SVG ID: https://jsfiddle.net/jfowu0xn/1/

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="datClip">
      <path d="M50,0 h400 a50,50 0 0 1 50,50 v0 a50,50 0 0 1 -50,50 h-400 a50,50 0 0 1 -50,-50 v0 a50,50 0 0 1 50,-50 M50,10 a40,40 0 0 0 -40,40 v0 a40,40 0 0 0 40,40 h400 a40,40 0 0 0 40,-40 v0 a40,40 0 0 0 -40,-40 h-400 z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
...
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#datClip);
  clip-path: url(#datClip);
...
```

The only thing I can figure out that works down to IE11 is to put the gradient in the SVG, base64 encode it, and slap it on as a background-image. This doesn't work in Chrome though haha: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lhosj53/

The SVG is width, height, and gradient dependent and I'm writing a UI framework so every combo of those things is another ~800 bytes of SVG in the page. Ugh.

Is there something better without base64? Is there something without all of this duplication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS media queries to detect Microsoft Edge browser, then, using the base64 data. Code as below (https://jsfiddle.net/Lacwmyeg/):

```
    body {
        background: pink;
    }
    div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
        border-radius: 50px;
        z-index: 2;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    div:after {
        content: '';
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        box-sizing: inherit;
        position: inherit;
        background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
        -webkit-clip-path: url(#datClip);
        clip-path: url(#datClip);
    }

    @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
        /* IE Edge 16+ CSS */
        div:after { 
            background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIj4gPGRlZnM-IDxjbGlwUGF0aCBpZD0iZGF0Q2xpcCI-IDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik01MCwwIGg0MDAgYTUwLDUwIDAgMCAxIDUwLDUwIHYwIGE1MCw1MCAwIDAgMSAtNTAsNTAgaC00MDAgYTUwLDUwIDAgMCAxIC01MCwtNTAgdjAgYTUwLDUwIDAgMCAxIDUwLC01MCBNNTAsMTAgYTQwLDQwIDAgMCAwIC00MCw0MCB2MCBhNDAsNDAgMCAwIDAgNDAsNDAgaDQwMCBhNDAsNDAgMCAwIDAgNDAsLTQwIHYwIGE0MCw0MCAwIDAgMCAtNDAsLTQwIGgtNDAwIHoiIC8-IDwvY2xpcFBhdGg-IDxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0ibXlHcmFkaWVudCI-IDxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iNSUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9InJlZCIgLz4gPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSI5NSUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9ImJsdWUiIC8-IDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ-IDwvZGVmcz4gPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjUwMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAiIGNsaXAtcGF0aD0idXJsKCNkYXRDbGlwKSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNteUdyYWRpZW50KSI-PC9yZWN0PiA8L3N2Zz4");
        }
    }
```

Besides, there have another sample code without using SVG and base64 data, you could refer to it (https://jsfiddle.net/Lacwmyeg/1/):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .gradient-box {
        display: flex;
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: #fff;
        background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
        background-clip: padding-box;
        border: solid 5px transparent;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

        .gradient-box:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            margin: -5px;
            border-radius: inherit;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
        }

    body {
        margin: auto;
        background: pink;
    }
</style>
<div class="gradient-box">
    <div style="border-radius: 50px; background-color:papayawhip; width:100%">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because it’s a UI framework I’m generating CSS and HTML at runtime so different stuff for IE vs. WebKit isn’t an issue. I can’t use the z-index -1 trick because I need to support full transparency inside the gradient border and the weird stacking context rules would put the gradient behind siblings of the box.